# Sorting Algorithm for Binary Choice Rating

Tags: algorithm

Imagine a list of books that I want to order by how much I like them. Instead of rating individual books, I select the best out of two (randomly chosen) books from the list, and repeat this for as many pairs as I want (not rating all combinations).

How do I sort my book list based on this binary choice? Does this problem have an official name?

Comment: When you say "randomly chosen," do you mean that you have no choice over what books are picked?  Or that you can pick whatever books you want?

Comment: I mean that I have no choice over what books are picked. They are randomly chosen from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) of the books and then get them two by two. Comparing just two instances is either a stretch to be called sorting or it could be said to be the very core.

Comment: Thanks! That should work, but I won't choose an answer for a little bit to see what others may or may not come up with.

Answer (score 3):

As [Jonas Elfström](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602097/sorting-algorithm-for-binary-choice-rating/4602161#4602161) points out, Fisher-Yates is the canonical way to shuffle a set and this is probably a good idea as it will allow you to get data for every item. I think that you probably want more than one pass though. Essentially, what you are doing when sorting a collection of items is building a directed graph where the nodes are the items and the edges represent the relation *is greater than or equal to*. When one can algorithmically define this relation, then a single pass will suffice and you will end up with a well ordered set.

The complication here is that it is very believable that looking at books two at a time and letting a human decide without a well-define algorithm, one will end up with a situation where A > B, B > C and C > A. This will clearly not yield a well ordered set. Even worse, on two different days, one could give two different answers for the same two books.

The best way that I can think of to do this is to maintain an `n`x`n` matrix where `n` is the amount of items to be sorted. the `i, j` entry is the amount of times that item `i` was selected as being better than item `j`. Here, `i` indexes rows and `j` indexes columns.

From here, [PageRank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) which is unfortunately patented<sup>1</sup>, would be ideal. Not quite as elegant, but possibly good enough would be to sum the difference between `a`<sub>`ij`</sub> and `a``ji` and then sort the books based on that. So for example, sorting three books

```
   A B C
   _ _ _
 A|0 3 2
 B|2 0 3
 C|1 2 0
```

would mean that `A` was rated as better than `B` 3 times and better than `C` 2 times. Summing the rows gives

```
 A: (AB - BA) + (AC - CA) = (3 - 2) + (2 - 1) = 2
 B: (BA - AB) + (BC - CB) = (2 - 3) + (3 - 2) = 0
 C: (CA - AC) + (CB - BC) = (1 - 2) + (2 - 3) = -2
```

So they would sort as `A > B > C`.

---

If you aren't going to use page rank, then you can eliminate the matrix and get identical results by associating an integer initialized to 0 for each book. When `A` is selected over `B`, increment the integer associated with `A` and decrement the integer associated with `B`.

<sup>1 Sorry for rant but I have know idea how you patent what's essentially a mathematical result.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for stiring up old question, but I think this will be useful for you.

When I worked on same task, I choose online insertion sort. This is perfect choice on small collection. For example, for 10 books you should do only 14 comparisons (in average case). In best case you should do only 9 comparisions (if your collection is already sorted).

If you choose quick sort, you should do 20 comparisons (average), but it's always better then dirty sorting (by comparing each book with all books in collection).

Anyway, you should do online ranking (next pair selection based on previous comparision results).

Note that all of this solutions has one assumption about transitive relation (If book1 is better then book2 and book2 better than book3, then book1 better then book3). If it is not working for you – you can't rank them.

You can find both algorithms perfectly described on Wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_sort